# Propriedades dinâmicas no vue 2

Tags: vue.js

Estou estudando frameworks reativos para um projeto, e uma das funcionalidades que preciso é a criação de propriedades dinâmicas, em `angularJs` bastava iniciar um `ng-model` que a propriedade era criada, mas vejo que isso não é possível em Vue 2, Por que ? existe outra forma de fazer isso ou outro framework atual que permite isso?

Comment: O Vue tem o `v-model`, não é semelhante ao `ng-model`? Podes explicar melhor a funcionalidade que procuras?

Comment: @Sergio, quando inicio um `v-model` ele me obriga a instanciar a propriedade vazia em `data{}`, teria como instanciar `v-model` e ele criar a propriedade caso não exista, como em `angularjs`? (meus testes foram online caso esteja falando besteira)

Comment: De facto tens de ter declarado no `data`. Podes explicar o que estás a fazer, talvez haja uma maneira _"à lá Vue"_ de fazer isso...

Comment: Digamos que eu esteja criando um elemento dinamicamente, exemplo uma div, ao criar essa div gostaria de referencia-la como propriedade, para que pudesse mexer em coisas como style, porém individualmente.

Comment: Podes fazer isso com `ref`?

Comment: Não conhecia o ref, acredito que sirva para o meu problema, teria como me dar um exemplo de uso?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/50wL7mdz/71248/

Comment: Isso resolve boa parte dos meus problemas, obrigado! caso queria responder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar variáveis de dinâmicas, poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
1 - Criar uma variáveis que receberá as variáveis dinâmicas
2 - Fazer um loop para exibi-las
3 - Utilizar this.$set e this.$delete para criar e removê-las
```

Segue um exemplo de código.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      variaveis: {}
    };
  },
  beforeMount: function() {
    this.add();
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.$set(this.variaveis, 'campo1', {
        nome: 'Campo 01',
        valor: 'Valor 01'
      });
    },
    remover: function(key) {
      this.$delete(this.variaveis, key)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>É possível criar as propriedades dinamicamente com o vm.$set.</p>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(variavel, key) in variaveis">
      <label>{{ variavel.nome }}</label>
      <input v-model="variavel.valor" :placeholder="variavel.nome" type="text">
      <button v-on:click="remover(key)">Remover</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ variaveis }}</pre>
  <button v-if="Object.keys(variaveis).length == 0" v-on:click="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

Obs.: Fiz a utilização desta técnica para criar um page builder com Vue. A diferença é que tenho diversas tratativas e na criação de cada elemento eu digo o tipo em uma propriedade.

Comment: Opa, realmente $set e $delete serão perfeitos para o meu caso, obrigado Bruno!

Answer (score 1):

Em Vue como referiste ele obriga a instanciar a propriedade vazia em `data`.

Uma solução é criar uma referência ao elemento criado no template com `ref`. Assim no template podes ter `ref="nome"` e depois podes usar `this.$refs.nome.style.color = 'blue';`

Isto pode ser util em casos de posicionamento por exemplo mas deve ser evitado para inserir HTML para evitar possíveis ataques.

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/50wL7mdz/71248/